# Why does Subtraction float from Integer return a fasle Value?

Tags: c

Im trying to get only the number after the dot in a number

```
float number;
printf("Enter a real number:\n");
scanf("%f", &number);
int integerPart = (int)number;
int fractionalPart = (int)((number -(float)integerPart) *1000);
printf("The fractional part: %d\n", fractionalPart);
```

when i put 256.589 i get output of 588
why?

Comment: _Why does Dividing float...?_ I don't see any division here

Comment: @B001 I think he might mean "separating" with the use of the term "dividing".

Comment: Use `scanf("%f", &number); printf("%.20e\n", number);` to see the result of data entry and that `number` is not _exactly_ 256.589 but maybe 2.56588989257812500000e+02